# How to "Schedule Automatic Backups" of your Google Sheets as Excel

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, export-to-excel

How to "Schedule Automatic Backups" of your Google Sheets as Excel
in  specific folder in google drive
I have a code to save a backup
It was prepared with Google Sheet code editor
But it saves the file as Google Sheet, but it needs to be saved as Excel
I found this code
https://gist.github.com/abhijeetchopra/99a11fb6016a70287112
But I need an excel backup

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Modifying the reference you provided, try to export the file to xlsx and then have it created by using its blob into the desired directory.

#### Script:

```
function makeCopy() {
  // generates the timestamp and stores in variable formattedDate as year-month-date hour-minute-second
  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd' 'HH:mm:ss");

  // gets the name of the original file and appends the word "copy" followed by the timestamp stored in formattedDate
  var name = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getName() + " Copy " + formattedDate;

  // gets the destination folder by their ID. REPLACE xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx with your folder's ID that you can get by opening the folder in Google Drive and checking the URL in the browser's address bar
  var destination = DriveApp.getFolderById("xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  // get xlsx export link 
  var url = "https://docs.google.com/feeds/download/spreadsheets/Export?key=" + ss.getId() + "&exportFormat=xlsx";

  var params = {
    method      : "get",
    headers     : {"Authorization": "Bearer " + ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()},
    muteHttpExceptions: true
  };

  var blob = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, params).getBlob();

  blob.setName(name + ".xlsx");
  destination.createFile(blob);
}
```

#### Output:

[image: output]

#### Note:

- The reference you included already have the steps to do the scheduling of automatic backups so that should suffice for the automation.